# INNER JOIN creates a memory issue

Tags: android, sqlite

In an Android application and SQLite,

`INNER JOIN` in a `QUERY` creates memory problem as following:

> Window is full: requested allocation 372 bytes, free space 106 bytes,
>   window size 2097152 bytes

***The QUERY is as following:***

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA A 
INNER JOIN TABLEB B 
ON A.ID1 = B.ID1 AND A.ID2 = B.ID2 
WHERE B.DATA3 = 'Y'
```

***Table A is composed of the following 4 columns:***

```
ID1,ID2,DATA1,DATA2: 

ID1   ID2   DATA1   DATA2 
A     E     D1      D4
B     F     D2      D5
C     G     D3      D6
D     H     D4      D7
```

***Table B is composed of the following 3 columns:***

```
ID1,ID2,DATA3: 

ID1   ID2   DATA3 
A     E     Y
B     F     N
C     G     Y
D     H     N
```

***The QUERY result is as following:***

```
ID1   ID2   DATA1   DATA2 
A     E     D1      D4
C     G     D3      D6
```

The point is when I increase the number of records to several thousands, I see the problem and it works fine for less records

Another point is to test the memory issue, I used another `QUERY` to retrieve data just from Table A without `INNER JOIN` with Table B and the retrieved record number is the same as the retrieved record number of the Queri above with INNER JOIN, but there is no memory problem
So I concluded that the INNER JOIN is creating the memory problem
In other word the problem is not the number of records as the result of the `QUERY` with INNER JOIN is too much cause I get that much records with other `QUERY`'s without any memory problem

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join):

> Conversely, an inner join can result in disastrously slow performance or even a server crash when used in a large volume query in combination with database functions in an SQL Where clause.[2][3][4] A function in an SQL Where clause can result in the database ignoring relatively compact table indexes. The database may read and inner join the selected columns from both tables before reducing the number of rows using the filter that depends on a calculated value, resulting in a relatively enormous amount of inefficient processing.

Comment: So what to do ?